# How do I check if the Android rating bar is empty for a particular object? The null check doesnt seem to working

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have a ratings bar to rate movies and I want to hide the rating bar if there aren't any ratings. I have implemented a null check but that doesnt seem to be working!

Comment: Check the Float value of your Rating bar ==0 then  hide your rating

Answer (score 1):

float is a primitive data type and not an object. null check is used for objects. For primitives you should use the default values check. For float the default value is 0.0f.

Check [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for info

**Example**

```
  float x = 0.0f;
 if (x == 0) {
            System.out.println("Value is ZERO>>>>>");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Value is NOT ZERO>>>>>");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have assigned values to rating bar from model classes in your case its movies then you will have the value of rating (float/integer) just use that to make decision about weather to show rating bar or no.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem, mRating is a string type

```
 if(Float.parseFloat(mRating)==0)
        {
            Layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```